# Show the amount of visitors for a Bolt page in the frontend?

Tags: bolt-cms

I want to show the amount of visitors for a Bolt page in the frontend. I could not find a proper solution for this in the docs or in the extensions.

Is this possible with Twig? Or should I use a third-party solution?

Answer (score 2):

From the point of view of Twig, no.  You would need a reliable way to log each visit, remove bots and crawlers and still no trash your database.

I wrote something for WP once, well twice actually, that attempted to do the visit tracking but it ended up putting a lot of pressure on the backend to track things that people like Google had far better resources to handle in terms of a) knowing what should be considered a 'real' visitor, and b) storing/processing the associated data.

Answer (score 1):

What you however could do, implement Google Analytics to log the visitors and then use the API to display visitors on the front-end.

Might be quite a hassle to figure out how the API works for certain pages, but it will solve your problem.

Good luck!

Also see https://developers.google.com/analytics/